# How to get the exact resoutions list for Video recording using camera2 api?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-camera2, android-debug

I'm making a custom camera application for android. I'm recording the videos using camera2 API.

But I want to get the list of resolutions supported by the device. So that I can record the videos according to the supported video resolutions and pass the exact size in:

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(height,width)
```

I have used 2 options to get the video camera resolutions list

1 Using StreamConfigurationMap:

```
val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
val map: StreamConfigurationMap? = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
val sizes = map?.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
```

But it's giving me 4K resolution in some devices, which the device does not support for recording the videos.
I have also used **map?.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder::class.java)**, but it's also giving 4K resolution, which is not supported by the device for video recording.

2 Using the CamcorderProfile:

```
val has4KResolution = CamCorderProfile.hasProfile(deviceId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_2160P)
```

I am getting **false** in some devices **which support 4K resolution.**

Is there any other solution, by which I can get/fetch the supported video resolutions of the camera?

Any other ideas will also be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know these devices support 4K resolution?  

The default camera app on the device sometimes has back doors / special hacks to enable things like 4K, which aren't always available to normal apps.

Comment: It is good to see that you always replied to my questions. But @EddyTalvala there should be some trick or solution to get the exact video resolutions supported by the camera. Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

[CamcorderProfile](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/CamcorderProfile) lists the sizes the device manufacturer wants to support for video recording, so it's the simplest thing to look at.

The camera may support higher resolutions than that, for other use cases, so looking at the sizes from camera itself isn't terribly reliable.

It's likely possible other (maybe larger) sizes are available if you query the [MediaCodecList](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaCodecList)'s video encoders or similar.  But it's a bit of work to iterate that list and figure out what encoder type and sizes supported are.

So sticking to what CamcorderProfile says is supported is the safest option.

Comment: I have already tried CamCorder Profile but it didn't work with every device. It was giving true for OnePlus 6T and Pixel 2Xl and false for Galaxy M51 and Realme X2 which also support 4K resolution. 
Would you please provide some code of MediaCodec for fetching video resolutions supported by the device?

Comment: If CamcorderProfile doesn't list 4K, then realistically that device doesn't support 4K recording for apps.